# How can I export an Adobe Connect recording as a video?

Tags: adobe, video-streaming, video-capture, conference

I have links to recorded conferences, how can I export video from them?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

1. Log into your Adobe Connect account
2. Click on *Meetings > **My Meetings***
3. Click on the link for the recording
4. Click the “**Recordings**” link (right-side of screen)
5. Click the link in the “*Name*” column
6. Copy the “*URL for Viewing*” – Example, http://mycompany.adobeconnect.com/p12345678/
7. Paste it into a new browser tab then add the following to the end of the URL: `output/filename.zip?download=zip`
8. Your URL should look similar to this example, http://mycompany.adobeconnect.com/p12345678/output/filename.zip?download=zip

Comment: 1. Unzip the downloaded recording to a directory
2. Download and install "FLV Editor Lite" http://www.exp-flv.com/flv-editor/ 
3. Import> FLV and choose the "screenshare...flv" file you extracted.
4. Import> FLV and choose the "audio...flv" file (or "voip...flv") you extracted.
5. Drag the screenshare item to the "video" area of the timeline
6. Drag the audio or VOIP item to the "audio" area of the timeline
7. Choose Export > FLV and give the file a name.

Comment: your link is not accessible, do you have another link to FLV Editor Lite?

Comment: The site for "FLV Editor Lite" no longer exists, is there any other app which can do the same?

Comment: Is there any equivalent URL to `output/filename.zip?download=zip`  for `BigBlueButton` recordings, that gives an accumulated archive of media files and their metadata?

Comment: It did not work for me, it downloaded a folder but the files were too small to and not working. The Chrome network snipping worked better.

Answer (score 24):

I wrote this Python script to export an Adobe Connect recording as a video:

```py
'''
Requirements:
- python 2.7 or 3
- wget, unzip, and ffmpeg accessible from command line.

Examples:
python connect2vid_v2.py https://my.adobeconnect.com/pqc06mcawjgn/  --output_filename=" Understanding how the Network impacts your service"

Please email Franck Dernoncourt <franck.dernoncourt@gmail.com> if you improve this code.
'''

import shlex
import subprocess
import os
import glob
import argparse
import sys
import re


def run_command(command):
    print('running command: {0}'.format(command))
    process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    while True:
        output = process.stdout.readline()
        print(output.strip())
        if output == b'' and process.poll() is not None:
            print('Done running the command.')
            break
        if output:
            print(output.strip())
    rc = process.poll()
    return rc

def create_folder_if_not_exists(directory):
    '''
    Create the folder if it doesn't exist already.
    '''
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)

def extract_connect_id(parser, args):
    '''
    Function written by Aaron Hertzmann
    '''
    # ----- extract the connectID or ZIP file  -----

    if len(args.URLorIDorZIP) < 1:
    #    print('Error: No Connect recording URL provided.')
        parser.print_help()
        sys.exit(0)

    if args.URLorIDorZIP[0][-4:].lower() == '.zip':
        sourceZIP = args.URLorIDorZIP[0]
        connectID = os.path.basename(sourceZIP[:-4])
    elif len(args.URLorIDorZIP[0]) == 12:
        connectID = args.URLorIDorZIP[0]
    else:
        s = args.URLorIDorZIP[0].split('/')
        connectID = None
        for i in range(len(s)-1):
            if 'adobeconnect.com' in s[i]:
                connectID = s[i+1]
                break
        if connectID == None:
            print("Error: couldn't parse URL")
            sys.exit(1)

    return connectID


def main():
    '''
    This is the main function
    '''

    # ================ parse the arguments (part of the parsing code was written by Aaron Hertzmann) ======================

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Download an Adobe Connect recording and convert to a video file.')
    parser.add_argument('URLorIDorZIP', nargs='*', help='URL, code, or ZIP file for the Connect recording')
    parser.add_argument('--output_folder',default='output_videos',help='Folder for output files')
    parser.add_argument('--output_filename',default='noname', help='output_filename')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    #main_output_folder = "all_videos"
    main_output_folder = args.output_folder
    output_filename = args.output_filename
    output_filename =  re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','', output_filename)
    output_filename = output_filename.replace('@', '').strip()
    print('output_filename: {0}'.format(output_filename))
    connect_id = 'pul1pgdvpr87'
    connect_id = 'p6vwxp2d0c2f'
    connect_id = extract_connect_id(parser, args)
    video_filename = 'hello'
    video_filename = output_filename

    # ================ Download video  ======================
    output_folder = connect_id
    output_zip_filename = '{0}.zip'.format(connect_id)
    create_folder_if_not_exists(output_folder)
    create_folder_if_not_exists(main_output_folder)

    # Step 1: retrieve audio and video files
    connect_zip_url = 'https://my.adobeconnect.com/{0}/output/{0}.zip?download=zip'.format(connect_id)
    wget_command = 'wget -nc -O {1} {0}'.format(connect_zip_url, output_zip_filename) # -nc, --no-clobber: skip downloads that would download to existing files.
    run_command(wget_command)
    unzip_command = 'unzip -n {0} -d {1}'.format(output_zip_filename, output_folder) # -n: Unzip only newer files.
    run_command(unzip_command)

    # Step 2: create final video output
    cameraVoip_filepaths = []
    for filepaths in sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(output_folder, 'cameraVoip_*.flv'))):
        cameraVoip_filepaths.append(filepaths)
    print('cameraVoip_filepaths: {0}'.format(cameraVoip_filepaths))

    screenshare_filepaths = []
    for filepaths in sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(output_folder, 'screenshare_*.flv'))):
        screenshare_filepaths.append(filepaths)

    part = 0
    output_filepaths = []
    for cameraVoip_filepath, screenshare_filepath in zip(cameraVoip_filepaths, screenshare_filepaths):
        output_filepath = os.path.join(main_output_folder, '{0}_{1:04d}.flv'.format(video_filename, part))
        #output_filepath = '{0}_{1:04d}.flv'.format(video_filename, part)
        output_filepaths.append(output_filepath)
        # ffmpeg command from Oliver Wang / Yannick Hold-Geoffroy / Aaron Hertzmann
        conversion_command = 'ffmpeg -i "%s" -i "%s" -c copy -map 0:a:0 -map 1:v:0 -shortest -y "%s"'%(cameraVoip_filepath, screenshare_filepath, output_filepath)
        # -y: override output file if exists
        run_command(conversion_command)
        part += 1

    # Concatenate all videos into one single video
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333232/how-to-concatenate-two-mp4-files-using-ffmpeg
    video_list_filename = 'video_list.txt'
    video_list_file = open(video_list_filename, 'w')
    for output_filepath in output_filepaths:
        video_list_file.write("file '{0}'\n".format(output_filepath))
    video_list_file.close()
    final_output_filepath = '{0}.flv'.format(video_filename)
    # ffmpeg command from Oliver Wang / Yannick Hold-Geoffroy / Aaron Hertzmann
    conversion_command = 'ffmpeg -safe 0 -y -f concat -i "{1}" -c copy "{0}"'.format(final_output_filepath, video_list_filename)
    run_command(conversion_command)
    #os.remove(video_list_filename)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    #cProfile.run('main()') # if you want to do some profiling
```

---

Explanation on how the script works:

Assume that the Adobe Connect ID is p6vwxp2d0c2f, i.e. the URL is https://my.adobeconnect.com/p6vwxp2d0c2f. You can add `/output/p6vwxp2d0c2f.zip?download=zip` at the end of the URL to download some zip archive containing a bunch of audio and video files as well as some .xml files. E.g., https://my.adobeconnect.com/p6vwxp2d0c2e/output/p6vwxp2d0c2e.zip?download=zip could contain:

```
 Directory of C:\Users\[...]\p6vwxp2d0c2f

02/09/2019  11:27 AM    <DIR>          .
02/09/2019  11:27 AM    <DIR>          ..
02/09/2019  11:00 AM        52,239,473 cameraVoip_1_11.flv
02/09/2019  11:00 AM         1,364,573 cameraVoip_1_11.xml
02/09/2019  11:00 AM         7,176,904 cameraVoip_1_15.flv
02/09/2019  11:00 AM           188,012 cameraVoip_1_15.xml
02/09/2019  11:00 AM             6,004 cameraVoip_1_3.flv
02/09/2019  11:00 AM             1,698 cameraVoip_1_3.xml
02/09/2019  11:00 AM        62,603,505 cameraVoip_1_7.flv
02/09/2019  11:00 AM         1,625,383 cameraVoip_1_7.xml
02/09/2019  11:00 AM             2,249 ftcontent1.flv
02/09/2019  11:00 AM             8,219 ftcontent1.xml
02/09/2019  11:00 AM            25,685 ftcontent13.flv
02/09/2019  11:00 AM            85,464 ftcontent13.xml
02/09/2019  11:00 AM           199,781 ftcontent5.flv
02/09/2019  11:00 AM           657,091 ftcontent5.xml
02/09/2019  11:00 AM           182,297 ftcontent9.flv
02/09/2019  11:00 AM           601,758 ftcontent9.xml
02/09/2019  11:00 AM             1,354 fttitle0.flv
02/09/2019  11:00 AM             3,272 fttitle0.xml
02/09/2019  11:00 AM             1,354 fttitle12.flv
02/09/2019  11:00 AM             3,298 fttitle12.xml
02/09/2019  11:00 AM             1,354 fttitle4.flv
02/09/2019  11:00 AM             3,290 fttitle4.xml
02/09/2019  11:00 AM             1,354 fttitle8.flv
02/09/2019  11:00 AM             3,298 fttitle8.xml
02/09/2019  11:00 AM         1,815,158 indexstream.flv
02/09/2019  11:00 AM         7,703,603 indexstream.xml
02/09/2019  11:00 AM         5,316,597 mainstream.flv
02/09/2019  11:00 AM        21,259,001 mainstream.xml
02/09/2019  11:00 AM       217,448,561 screenshare_2_10.flv
02/09/2019  11:01 AM         1,364,572 screenshare_2_10.xml
02/09/2019  11:01 AM        32,364,457 screenshare_2_14.flv
02/09/2019  11:01 AM           188,011 screenshare_2_14.xml
02/09/2019  11:01 AM           387,981 screenshare_2_2.flv
02/09/2019  11:01 AM             1,698 screenshare_2_2.xml
02/09/2019  11:01 AM       237,470,572 screenshare_2_6.flv
02/09/2019  11:01 AM         1,625,385 screenshare_2_6.xml
02/09/2019  11:01 AM                48 telephony-files.xml
02/09/2019  11:01 AM               691 transcriptstream.flv
02/09/2019  11:01 AM             2,391 transcriptstream.xml
              39 File(s)    653,935,396 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   1,590,358,016 bytes free
```

- cameraVoip_*_*.xml contains the audio + webcam if any.
- screenshare_*_*.xml contains the audio + webcam if any.

To merge them, you can use `ffmpeg` (I took the `ffmpeg` commands from Oliver Wang / Yannick Hold-Geoffroy / Aaron Hertzmann):

```
ffmpeg -i cameraVoip_1_11.flv -i screenshare_2_10.flv -c copy -map 0:a:0 -map 1:v:0 -shortest output.flv
```

where:

- `-map 0:a:0`: map the first input file to be used just for the audio.
- `-map 1:v:0`: map the second input file to be used just for the video.
- `-shortest`: cut the audio or video in case cameraVoip_1_11.flv and screenshare_2_10.flv don't have the same length.

If you want to keep the webcam video and place it in some corner of the video screen sharing:

```
ffmpeg -i cameraVoip_1_11.flv -i screenshare_2_10.flv  \
                         -filter_complex \
                         "color=s=1072x480:c=black [base]; [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=640x480 [upperleft]; [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=432x240 [upperright]; [base][upperleft] overlay=shortest=1 [tmp1]; [tmp1][upperright] overlay=shortest=1:x=640" \
                         -c:v libx264 -c:a mp2 output.mkv
```

---

Regarding mapping the cameraVoip_*_*.xml to the correct screenshare_*_*.xml, in case there is more than one:

One could look at the cameraVoip_*_*.xml / screenshare_*_*.xml to get the timestamps of when the audio / screen share video began. This allows to map the screenshare_*_*.xml with the correct cameraVoip_*_*.xml.

E.g., in https://my.adobeconnect.com/p6vwxp2d0c2f/output/p6vwxp2d0c2f.zip?download=zip, from cameraVoip_1_11.xml, line 21:

```
<String><![CDATA[Thu Feb 07 21:11:23 2019]]></String>
```

Otherwise, another way could be to sort cameraVoip_*_*.xml / screenshare_*_*.xml, then map the first cameraVoip_*_*.xml with the first screenshare_*_*.xml, the second cameraVoip_*_*.xml with the first screenshare_*_*.xml, etc. I don't know if it'd break in some cases (seems to be ok for the couple of Adobe Connect recordings I looked at but perhaps that's because people always share screens).

Comment: What if there wasn't any "screenshare" files, and the narrator was narrating over an uploaded PDF file or a presentation? how to export that?

Comment: It's not a good solution. not works sometimes

Answer (score 3):

Based on Franck's answer, I've created a tool to parse XML files of adobe connect downloaded zip file and output a single `.mkv` video file. It uses `ffmpeg` to create the video file and merge screen share and camera of presenter. It actually adds voice of viewers when they/presenter opens their microphones.

Here's the link to the project:
https://github.com/ali-em/AdobeCollect

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30019780)

Answer (score 2):

I made an application to use the **original recorder in adobe connect**, then all **Admin**, **non-Admin** and **Guest** users can use recording mode.

Follow the simple installation instructions in [Adobe Connect Record](https://github.com/MRT-77/AdobeConnectRecord)

**HOW TO USE**

1. Open your web browser and click on a webinar link
2. A console page will show up then type yes or just `y` then press enter.
   [image: Adobe Connect Record]
3. This is the result:
   [image: adobe connect]

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late to the party but see the below method for downloading from connect as a student or rather a consumer of the content.

1. Navigate to the web link of the recording which will open a new tab
   for playback.
2. Right click and inspect.
3. Navigate to the network tab and reload the page.
4. Locate the source that begins in "video.mp4"
5. Left click it and copy the request url header.
   [image]
6. Paste that into a new window that will open up another player with
   the option to download in the lower right hand corner.

Comment: This worked for me better. The other solutions no longer work. The FLV file was empty, but using this method, I got the file nice and easy!
Hint: You can also filter the network requests by 'Media' and it can be found easier!

Comment: Couldn't find the item starting with Video.

Answer (score 0):

In Connect Central, in the recording listings, there is a Make Offline link. This will create an FLV of the recording on your local machine. Unfortunately, creating this video this takes as long as the recording takes to play. Follow the guidance given by the app for best quality.

You can then transcode the FLV to the format you prefer.

You must be a host of the meeting recorded or have moved the recording into the content library.