# How to export Adobe Connect video?

Tags: ffmpeg, export, adobe-connect

I'm very new to all this, and learning. I followed the advice given here [How can I export an Adobe Connect recording as a video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179517/how-can-i-export-an-adobe-connect-recording-as-a-video) to download a video from an Adobe Connect recording, but there is no *Screenshare* in the folder I downloaded (have a look here [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brJBp.png)), although the lesson contained some slides to look at. How is this possible?

Thanks to anyone that can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Hi the best way to get the recording as a video file is to choose "Make offline" option in the recording listings.

The solution described [How can I export an Adobe Connect recording as a video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179517/how-can-i-export-an-adobe-connect-recording-as-a-video) here will not contain the contents shared via share pod.

Comment: I know, the problem is I'm not allowed to access the folder, as I'm just a participant.

Answer (score 0):

Hi
The downloaded zip file needs to be carefully checked, if you do not have information in this regard, you can easily and without any problem use the program I wrote to download your Adobe Connect session file and visit my github repository address for get more details .
Also You can solve your problem and convert your downloaded file to video and audio.
But it goes without saying that if you need text conversations, this program that I wrote is not suitable for you and is the best solution for you is recording videos from your the screen.

https://github.com/HosseinShams00/AdobeConnectDownloader